# Filter for the previous month only - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a data set for the past 11 months (from Apr 2019 to Feb 2020). I have created a pivot wherein I am trying to filter for all months except the current month. The Month is in the format - 1, 2, 3... and so on. The code I am using is as follows -

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Summary_2").PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 3
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Summary_2").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Summary_2").PivotFields("Month"). _
EnableMultiplePageItems = True
For Each pit In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Summary_2").PivotFields("Month")
.PivotItems("" = "& v").Visible = False
Next
End With
```

I am unable to get any result from this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only current month's data in the pivot, then use month number instead of (All), as in below code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Summary_2").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = Format(Date, "M")
```

If you don't need current month's data in the pivot, then use below code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Summary_2").PivotFields("Month").pivotitems(Format(Date, "M")).visible = False
```

Reference: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But actually I wanted to use this query over a period of months, hence the current month would keep changing. So it would be great if there is a solution which would select the current month when I run it in any month.

Comment: I have updated the code, you may check, if it works fine ?

Comment: You'r Welcome, Tushar